# Drupal 8 #attached not working inside eventsubscriber

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Hi All below Drupal 8 EventSubscriber class supposed to attach drupalSettings into Drupal 8 javascript settings. But unfortunately this  \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($js_data); not attaching the drupal javascript settings.

```
namespace Drupal\ejectorseat\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

class EjectorseatSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public function customEjector(GetResponseEvent $event) {
      $account = \Drupal::currentUser();
      $ejectorseat_interval = \Drupal::config('ejectorseat.settings')->get('ejectorseat_interval');
      if(empty($ejectorseat_interval)){
        $ejectorseat_interval = 60;
      }
      $ejectorseat_background = \Drupal::config('ejectorseat.settings')->get('ejectorseat_background');
      if(empty($ejectorseat_background)){
        $ejectorseat_background = 0;
      }

      if ($account->id() > 0 && (int) $ejectorseat_interval) {
          $js_data = array();
          $js_data['#attached']['drupalSettings']['ejectorSeat']['interval'] = $ejectorseat_interval;
          $js_data['#attached']['drupalSettings']['ejectorSeat']['url'] = Url::fromRoute('ejectorseat/check');
          $js_data['#attached']['drupalSettings']['ejectorSeat']['ignoreFocus'] = $ejectorseat_background ? TRUE : FALSE;
          \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($js_data);
      }
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('customEjector');
    return $events;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and i didn't find a OOP solution. 
In your case just place your logic form the customEjector Method in a HOOK called  **hook_js_settings_alter** in your **ejectorseat.module** file. This way you can be sure all variables are avaiable in the drupalSettings Object.

E.g just for demonstration:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_js_settings_alter().
 *
 */
function ejectorseat_js_settings_alter(array &$settings,
    \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets
) {
     ...

      $settings['all_settings'] = $globalSettings->getAll();
      //if you want to push only a single value
      $settings['custom_link'] = $globalSettings->get('custom_link')
      $settings['ejectorSeat']['interval'] = $ejectorseat_interval;
      $settings['ejectorSeat']['url'] = Url::fromRoute('ejectorseat/check');
      $settings['ejectorSeat']['ejectorSeat']['ignoreFocus'] = $ejectorseat_background ? TRUE : FALSE;

 }
```